# Vim: how to make buffers automatically split space evenly on window resize

Tags: vim

Right now, when I make the window size bigger in vim (running from the terminal), one buffer gets all the extra space while the other remains scrunched.  Is there a way to automatically resize the buffers so that each buffer gets half of the window size (or 1/N space for N buffers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good question! I had never thought of this, but now that I think about it, the same thing has been bugging me too!

You can use the key combination <kbd>ctrl-w</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> to resize all splits to their appropriate size. From `:help CTRL-W_=`

```
                        *CTRL-W_=*
CTRL-W =    Make all windows (almost) equally high and wide, but use
        'winheight' and 'winwidth' for the current window.
        Windows with 'winfixheight' set keep their height and windows
        with 'winfixwidth' set keep their width.
```

However, this is annoying to have do do every time you resize your screen. You can automate this with autocommands:

```
autocmd WinResize * wincmd =
```

This will make it so that every time you resize vim, it will *automagically* press <kbd>ctrl-w</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> for you so that you don't have to worry about it.

I have confirmed that this works on both terminal and GUI versions.

This is a great setting. In fact, I ended up [adding it to my personal settings,](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/dotFiles/blob/master/.vimrc#L187) so thanks for asking this question!

Comment: No prob, thanks for the detailed answer.  Glad my ignorance could be of use!

Comment: I don't have a `WinResize` event on Vim 8.0.0019, installed via Homebrew 1.0.6-31-gfaebc64. I was however able to use the `VimResized` event.